# Replace a middle string in .bat file using AutoHotKey without deleting file

Tags: autohotkey

I need to edit standalone.bat file using ahk script. I want to increase my heap size using ahk so below is line where i have to change heap in my bat file. Now i have trying to edit this using StringReplace and FileAppend but **FileAppend keeps on appending string to the end**

from

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Xms64M -**Xmx1426M** %JAVA_OPTS%"

to

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Xms64M -**Xmx1426M** %JAVA_OPTS%"**xms000M**

I am new to .ahk, i have tried this using some search

```
Loop, read, C:\standalone.bat

{
 Line = %A_LoopReadLine%
 replaceto = xms000M
 IfInString, Line, Xmx1426M 
    , Line, replaceto, %Line%, %replaceto%      
    FileAppend, %replaceto%`n
 StringReplace FileAppend
}
```

Is it possible to replace middle string using ahk. thanks

Comment: the ahk code you've posted will not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fileappend will always append to the end of a file. Why do you want to prevent a temporary deletion of your batch file?

Typically, in ahk, you'd do it like this..

```
batFile = C:\standalone.bat

output := ""
Loop, read, %batFile%
{
    Line = %A_LoopReadLine%
    IfInString, Line, Xmx1426M
    {
        StringReplace, Line, Line, Xmx1426M, xms000M
        ; note: Regular Expressions can be used like Line := regExReplace(Line, "...", "...")
    }

    output .= Line . "`n"   ; note: this is the same as if to say output = %output%%Line%`n or output := output . line "`n"
}

FileDelete, %batFile%
FileAppend, %output%, %batFile%
```

This will delete your file for some little milliseconds, just to recreate it with the new content afterwards. I don't really see any difference to editing it without deletion, because in either way, you'll need write access to the file.

---

Some words about your code sample:

```
IfInString, Line, Xmx1426M 
    , Line, replaceto, %Line%, %replaceto%
```

will be interpreted as

> "If the string 'Line' contains 'Xmx1426M , Line, replaceto, %Line%, %replaceto%'"

which does not make any greater sense.

`FileAppend, %replaceto%\n` is lacking a destination file.

`StringReplace FileAppend`: these are two commands without any further parameters. You must never put two non-function-commands in the same line!